# VB.NET set Data Source, DisplayMember and ValueMember of checkedListBox from List of Dictionaries

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array, checkedlistbox

I have a `List` of `Dictionaries<String, String>`, each `Dictionary` hold 3 Key/value pairs (`Type`, `Id`, `Name`)

This [Post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5733352b-6d4e-41e3-8a82-ba7593fcbeba/adding-dictionary-type-list-to-checkedlistbox?forum=winforms) shows a nice way of using a binding source to bind a `Dictionary` to a `CheckedListBox`. Is there any way to accomplish a similar result using a `List` of `Dictionaries<String, String>` in the following format?

```
With CheckedListBox1
    .DataSource = TheList
    .DisplayMember = item("Name") 
    .ValueMember = item("Id")
End With
```

Comment: You cant use the list of Dictionaries because that would mean 9 possible values.  A single dictionary could be the datasource though.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and improvements, I hope the edited question conforms to standard

Comment: You should study the link you posted.  Displaymember and ValueMember are the *property names* - strings.  using a dictionary you would use "Key" and "Value".  Do you really want the contents of *all three* Dictionaries to be available?

Answer (score 0):

If all 3 dictionaries hold the same information, and everything is unique, you could use one dictionary as the source.

For 3 dictionaries you would have to flatten them first, like so:

```
Dim dataSrc = dictionaryList.SelectMany(Function(d) d.Select(Function(kvp) kvp))
```